# Do all crypto brokerages use the same database?

Tags: exchanges, currencies, exchange-fees, exchange-software

I am wondering if I submit a sell order for Bitcoin on Webull, do Robinhood users also see my order, allowing us to trade cryptocurrencies between different platforms?

If not, what is the largest crypto brokerage that also offers lower fees and good data/analytics tools?